# How to get text after <br/> tag in div?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, formatting

I wrote a script to download lyrics from the  internet in just a second. The text of lyrics in div with `<br>` at the end of line. when I trying to get text through BeautifulSoup. I'm getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "/home/rohit/Desktop/lyrics_finder.py", line 27, in 
>      app = EpicLyricFinderApp()
>     File "/home/rohit/Desktop/lyrics_finder.py", line 10, in **init**
>       self.app()
>     File "/home/rohit/Desktop/lyrics_finder.py", line 21, in app
>       for i in container.get_text():
>   AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_text'

**I'd try many differnt way but I'd get solution of this problem**

**My Code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os, requests, re


class EpicLyricFinderApp:
    def __init__(self):
        self.text = '+'.join(input('Enter song name and also include singer: ').split(' '))
        self.url = "https://search.azlyrics.com/search.php?q=let+me+love+you{}".format(self.text)
        self.lyrics = ''
        self.app()
    def app(self):
        req = requests.get(self.url).content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req, 'html.parser')
        links = [link['href'] for link in soup.select('.text-left a')]

        # Open another url
        req1 = requests.get(links[0]).content
        soup1 = BeautifulSoup(req1, 'html.parser')
        container = soup1.select('body > div.container.main-page > div > div.col-xs-12.col-lg-8.text-center > div:nth-child(10)')

        for i in container.get_text():
            print(i)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = EpicLyricFinderApp()
```

**I expected:**

How can I skip `<br/>` in Beautifulsoup in order to get text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The container is list object not element.That is why you are getting this error.

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_text'

You need to get the text in iteration.

```
for i in container:
    print(i.get_text())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I forgot!